# Docker errors when trying to build in ARM64 Apple M1: "Failed to resolve full path of the current executable [/proc/self/exe]"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, apple-m1, .net-core-sdk

I'm having trouble building docker containers on an Apple M1
The project uses sdk 2.2 which is incompatible with arm64 architecture. So I changed the sdk and aspnet cores to 2.2-alpine3.8 and they seem to build ok but the process fails when it needs to publish

The docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine3.8 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish src/admin/MyContainer.Admin.csproj -c Release -o ./publish

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-alpine3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/admin/publish .

# Copy script that allows waiting for the database on docker-compose
# As referenced here https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/
# This was done because admin starts up very quickly on e2e env
# and the sqlserver container wasn't getting ready fast enough
COPY --from=build-env /app/docker-wait-for-it.sh .

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["dotnet", "MyContainer.Admin.dll"]
```

the build command I'm using is:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64/v8 -t MyContainer.azurecr.io/admin-api-web:development ./backend -f ./backend/Admin.Api.Web.Dockerfile
```

and the log output is:

```
[+] Building 0.5s (11/13)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 => [internal] load build definition from Admin.Api.Web.Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 46B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-alpine3.8                                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine3.8                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => [build-env 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine3.8@sha256:1299ac0379146c1de7b588196727dbd56eace3abfbdd4321c547c9ff4a18a2f7                                                                                       0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine3.8@sha256:1299ac0379146c1de7b588196727dbd56eace3abfbdd4321c547c9ff4a18a2f7                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-alpine3.8@sha256:4d6e528f4c09c55804b6032ecc5d60565a3ee16f68bb08d2cf337dff99cdb8c3                                                                                      0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-alpine3.8@sha256:4d6e528f4c09c55804b6032ecc5d60565a3ee16f68bb08d2cf337dff99cdb8c3                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.2s
 => => transferring context: 473.91kB                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [build-env 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build-env 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [build-env 4/4] RUN dotnet publish src/admin/MyContainer.Admin.csproj -c Release -o ./publish                                                                                                                                  0.1s
------
 > [build-env 4/4] RUN dotnet publish src/admin/MyContainer.Admin.csproj -c Release -o ./publish:
#11 0.127 Failed to resolve full path of the current executable [/proc/self/exe]
```

I've tried with different platforms on the --platform flag and without any specified as well... If I try to build with core 2.2 I get this output:

```
[+] Building 0.5s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Admin.Api.Web.Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 745B                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2                                                                                                                                                        0.4s
 => CANCELED [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2                                                                                                                                                        0.4s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2:
------
error: failed to solve: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:08xxx: not found
```

Which I've found out to be because core 2.2 has no support form arm64. But this file builds without any errors on an Intel MacBook but with M1 I can't get past the build error. Any ideas?

Comment: So far the only solution I've encountered is to update the containers to use the .NET5 version

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a followup to the problem,
which might shed some more light on the issue.

I'm using aspnet:6 and it passes the build.

The problem later on is that the runnable .dll throws

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

which seems to be a platform issue, using Mac with an M1 Silicon chipset.

I have no issue with other docker images that are made for linux/amd64

The Docker daemon seems to deal with this fine (having installed Rosetta2 and the Latest Docker Desktop for M1)
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/

Have you managed to resolve the issue and execute the dll?

Comment: The solution me and my team found was to update to .NET5 and higher... the build with .NET2 wouldn't work because it was too far behind and no compatibility at all with M1 chips... so far no problems with .NET5
and I was using the most recent docker desktop and rosetta 2 as well. From what I've read .NET6 would solve most(if not all) compatibility issues with M1